# Parent Child Collapse using Kend React Grid

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I want to achieve the attached image link ([Req1.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WE01Xdb0wc0HBvVGFIAELCmv56yDlv9D/view?usp=sharing)) functionality through the kendo react grid.

So, When User expands (+) on the 'campaign 2' from the first column it will display their all the children rows i.e Program1, Program2 ... etc. if User expands (+) program row then it will display Tactic2, Tactic3, ... etc Similarly for Tactic and Line Item. So, Expand (+) will be visible only based on their children's rows.

Could you please guide us on how to get this feature using Kendo React Grid?

[image: Req1.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything you're trying to accomplish is available in their documentation: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/grouping/

Keep in mind you'll have to set a default group field in the grid's state for it to render the grid grouped by default.